# How to get all reviews of "ANY" app from Google's playstore programatically?

Tags: android, python, google-api

Is it possible to get all reviews of any app from Playstore ?

I researched and came across new `Google Developer Review API` but I think it only works with app developed by me. 
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Can I use Google's developer review api for fetching reviews of any app on playstore ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could not find any available resource on internet to fulfill my request of reading reviews from playstore.

Some of the sources pointed me to the newly launched "Google Review" API but after wasting money I realized that the API only allows me to fetch reviews of ONLY MY APP. duhh..

Finally I created an automation to fetch reviews from playstore for "ANY" app. 
Please find the automation at https://github.com/shivang1989/playstoreReview

Simply fire the command `python getReviews.py` and provide package name of the app.

Automation will fetch all the reviews and store it in an html file named as following :

`<package-name>_decoded.html`.

Please note that this html will be raw output and contain all the reviews. You can use this html file as per your need.

I hope this will help others looking for similar requests. 
Thank you.

Comment: How did you integrated it with android? Can you please tell me that? I never used python script with android so I am pretty noob at it.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get your question. Do you want to achieve above functionality using an Android app ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good and well maintained Python library. Which provides APIs to easily crawl the Google Play Store for app details and review.

https://pypi.org/project/google-play-scraper/